# How can I create unique threads to handle(iterate) portions of a given number using #pragma - Openmp?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, openmp, pragma

So basically I'm new to Stackoverflow and to the whole **OpenMP** - **#pragma** parallel implementation of code... I have a decent idea of how threads work.

I'm trying to make a variable **'p'** (that will be incremented within a **while** loop(**NOT for loop**)), to be incremented in parts(ranges) by individually assigned threads using **#pragma** derivatives.

Algorithm Steps

1. Declare & define all necessary variables, functions and derivatives.
2. Declare parallel block using `#pragma omp parallel`
3. Instruct threads to handle a specific range of values belonging to a certain variable or function.
4. Instruct threads to divide total iteration size equally and then iterate variable simultaneously, each not necessarily being aware of the others value or iteration number but just focusing on doing their part.
5. Instruct threads to
   **(a)** handle a specific range of values belonging to a certain variable or function by dividing **total iteration size** equally and then iterate variable simultaneously.
   **(b)** Pass iterating value to function that is also being called by other `#pragma omp parallel` threads
6. These functions will return data back to certain functions that needs them. bool, string, int etc...

`total iteration size = 50`
How many Threads would divide **tits** equally... Yes **tits** is the short term for **t**otal_**it**eration_**s**ize... if it offends you then no Pun intended, if it doesn't then have a blast. <^_^>

Something like this:

```
int p = 0,total_iteration_size;
int tits = total_iteration_size;

while(p<=50) 
{
    //Create 5 parallel threads to iterate p by 10

    Thread1 = p++...  0-10 then print
    Thread2 = p++... 11-20 then print
    Thread3 = p++... 21-30 then print
    Thread4 = p++... 31-40 then print
    Thread5 = p++... 41-50 then print

    //In theory, Thread1 to Thread5 should iterate simultaneously in parallel the given variable while submission of value to print statement can be handled in any order. 


}
```

The above is the basics of the algorithm. In real application, the iteration involves forwarding of iterated value to inline functions that are also structured to handle tasks same approach - **using exact algorithm that handles parallel implementation of functions, iterations & Macros, Each Thread handling a defined range/number of functions to call**.

Scenario 2:

```
Another user case of this algorithm is..


while(p<=30) 
{
    Create 3 parallel threads to call function Foo() 10x each

    Thread1 = Foo();... 10 times
    Thread2 = Foo();... 10 times
    Thread3 = Foo();... 10 times

} 
return Foo();
```

**In the above scenario, function Foo() is called 10 times by each thread. Making a total of 30 calls.**

Scenario 3:

```
Another is.... 


while(p<=20) 
{
    //Create 2 parallel threads to iterate p by 10

    Thread1 = p++...  0-10 then print
    Thread2 = p++... 11-20 then print


Then:

    //Create 2 parallel threads to call function Foo(), using p as a passed parameter - 10x each. 

    Thread1 = Foo(p);... 10 times
    Thread2 = Foo(p);... 10 times

}
return Foo(p);
```

**In another scenario, individual threads call a function 10 times, but this time using variable `*p*` as a parameter.**

**simultaneously** meaning - range of operations being carried out by multiple cores in parallel. core1, core2, core3.... core8 each handling a specific thread.

Sorry don't mean to be picky/choosy but I don't need links or references to external sites of non coded answers... what I need are actual answers written in code.

I hope I was able to describe the design of the algorithm in a way that you guys can assist me with. Thanks in advance.

PS. `Thread1 = Foo(p);... 10 times` is just the best way I can describe what I want to achieve. Also other cpp files, programs and external functions might also depend on the result data of these parallel threads.

**Reference:**
[https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs3225-GIS/fall17/Lectures/openmp.html](https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/%7Eltoma/teaching/cs3225-GIS/fall17/Lectures/openmp.html)

Comment: PPS. I made use of the variable **```tits```** because, in the event that **```total_iteration_size```** is set to  **```private```** (in order to let each thread have their own copy of the variable and avoid race conditions) - if this is the case, I want to be able to make use of the values being created by each thread. This also applies to functions.  
Once again, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to first write your code as a regular `for`-loop, and then add `#pragma omp parallel for num_thread(2)` if you want it split over two threads. The reference you gave has examples, I suggest you try them out and modify them to suit your needs to get a feel of how OpenMP works. However, I would not hardcode the number of threads, just let OpenMP choose the right number of threads for you.

Comment: If you provide a serial [mre] and tell us which functions are computation expensive, we will tell you how to parallelize it using OpenMP.

Comment: @G. Sliepen....  Thanks

Comment: @Laci......  Alright.